# CMSIS arm_rfft_fast_f32 in place gives different results depending on the device

Tags: c, fft, in-place, cmsis

I've recently updated some code performing a real FFT for armV7M based micro-controllers. After noticing some regressions, **not all the time depending on the board I was testing on**, I found out the issue was that instead of using two different buffers for IN/OUT I used the same to do a modification in-place.

I had a look at the CMSIS documentation before doing this change and because It is using a complex FFT to do it and that the doc **does say [here](http://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/DSP/html/group__ComplexFFT.html)** in the `Description` part that the complex FFT is performed in place so I assumed It would work and It did but not on every device.

My question is why this changes is working on some devices and not one some others. I just can't figure it out. One of the working board is a [NucleoF429ZI](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f429zi.html) and the problematic one is the [MxChip](http://mxchip.com/az3166)

Thanks !